# Need historical prices of EUREX American and European style options

Tags: options, eurex

I am trying to get the historical price data on selected  American and European style options at EUREX. I am not familiar with their system. Does any one know whether they have something like yahoo finance where I can just download market data through R? Or at least, excel files with daily prices.
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately the only possibility to get data from the biggest option exchange of the world is to buy these from EUREX directly (or some other professional data provider) - and they are quite expensive.

More infos can be found here (and some sample files):
http://www.eurexchange.com/market/historical_data_en.html

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem. I am a student and doing it for my thesis. I emailed them asking if I can use their data for specific dates for free but haven't gotten an answer yet. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @GKED: What is the exact topic of your thesis? Perhaps there are other possibilites...